# Can't get the id out of an object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying just console.log(checkoutToken.id). However I cannot access this property and I do not understand why. I can print to the console the checkoutToken but cannot access the id property?

the fetchShippingCountries(checkoutToken.id) if is giving me the same problems. Am I not passing props correctly?

---

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  InputLabel,
  Select,
  MenuItem,
  Button,
  Grid,
  Typography,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { useForm, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import { commerce } from "../../lib/Commerce";
import FormInput from "../CheckoutForm/CustomTxtField";

const AddressForm = ({ checkoutToken, test }) => {
  const [shippingCountries, setShippingCountries] = useState([]);
  const [shippingCountry, setShippingCountry] = useState("");
  const [shippingSubdivisions, setShippingSubdivisions] = useState([]);
  const [shippingSubdivision, setShippingSubdivision] = useState("");
  const [shippingOptions, setShippingOptions] = useState([]);
  const [shippingOption, setShippingOption] = useState("");
  const methods = useForm();

  const fetchShippingCountries = async (checkoutTokenId) => {
    const countries = await commerce.services.localeListShippingCountries(
      checkoutTokenId
    );
    console.log(countries);
    setShippingCountries(countries);
    setShippingCountry(Object.keys(countries)[0]);
  };

  const fetchSubdivisions = async (countryCode) => {
    const subdivisions = await commerce.services.localeListSubdivisions(
      countryCode
    );

    setShippingSubdivisions(subdivisions);
    setShippingSubdivision(Object.keys(subdivisions)[0]);
  };

  const fetchShippingOptions = async (
    checkoutTokenId,
    country,
    stateProvince = null
  ) => {
    const options = await commerce.checkout.getShippingOptions(
      checkoutTokenId,
      { country, region: stateProvince }
    );

    setShippingOptions(options);
    setShippingOption(options[0].id);
  };
  console.log(checkoutToken);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchShippingCountries(checkoutToken);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchShippingCountries(checkoutToken.id);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shippingCountry) fetchSubdivisions(shippingCountry);
  }, [shippingCountry]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (shippingSubdivision)
      fetchShippingOptions(
        checkoutToken.id,
        shippingCountry,
        shippingSubdivision
      );
  }, [shippingSubdivision]);

  return (
    <div>
      <Typography variant="h6" gutterBottom>
        Shipping address
      </Typography>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form
          onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit((data) =>
            test({
              ...data,
              shippingCountry,
              shippingSubdivision,
              shippingOption,
            })
          )}
        >
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <FormInput required name="firstName" label="First name" />
            <FormInput required name="lastName" label="Last name" />
            <FormInput required name="address1" label="Address line 1" />
            <FormInput required name="email" label="Email" />
            <FormInput required name="city" label="City" />
            <FormInput required name="zip" label="Zip / Postal code" />
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <InputLabel>Shipping Country</InputLabel>
              <Select
                value={shippingCountry}
                fullWidth
                onChange={(e) => setShippingCountry(e.target.value)}
              >
                {Object.entries(shippingCountries)
                  .map(([code, name]) => ({ id: code, label: name }))
                  .map((item) => (
                    <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                      {item.label}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
              </Select>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <InputLabel>Shipping Subdivision</InputLabel>
              <Select
                value={shippingSubdivision}
                fullWidth
                onChange={(e) => setShippingSubdivision(e.target.value)}
              >
                {Object.entries(shippingSubdivisions)
                  .map(([code, name]) => ({ id: code, label: name }))
                  .map((item) => (
                    <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                      {item.label}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
              </Select>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <InputLabel>Shipping Options</InputLabel>
              <Select
                value={shippingOption}
                fullWidth
                onChange={(e) => setShippingOption(e.target.value)}
              >
                {shippingOptions
                  .map((sO) => ({
                    id: sO.id,
                    label: `${sO.description} - (${sO.price.formatted_with_symbol})`,
                  }))
                  .map((item) => (
                    <MenuItem key={item.id} value={item.id}>
                      {item.label}
                    </MenuItem>
                  ))}
              </Select>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <br />
          <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
            <Button component={Link} variant="outlined" to="/cart">
              Back to Cart
            </Button>
            <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
              Next
            </Button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddressForm;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Paper,
  Stepper,
  Step,
  StepLabel,
  Typography,
  CircularProgress,
  Divider,
  Button,
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

import useStyles from "./styles";
import AddressForm from "../AddressForm";
import PaymentForm from "../PaymentForm";
import { commerce } from "../../../lib/Commerce";

const steps = ["Shipping address", "Payment details"];

const Checkout = ({ cart }) => {
  const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = useState(0);
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [checkoutToken, setCheckoutToken] = useState(null);
  const [shippingData, setShippingData] = useState({});
  const history = useHistory();

  const nextStep = () => setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);
  const backStep = () => setActiveStep((prevActiveStep) => prevActiveStep + 1);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cart.id) {
      const generateToken = async () => {
        try {
          const token = await commerce.checkout.generateToken(cart.id, {
            type: "cart",
          });
          console.log(token);
          setCheckoutToken(token);
          console.log(checkoutToken);
        } catch (error) {
          if (activeStep !== steps.length) history.push("/");
        }
      };
      generateToken();
      console.log(checkoutToken.id);
    }
  }, []);
  const test = (data) => {
    setShippingData(data);

    nextStep();
  };

  const Conformation = () => <div>Conformation</div>;

  const Form = () =>
    activeStep === 0 ? (
      <AddressForm checkoutToken={checkoutToken} test={test} />
    ) : (
      <PaymentForm />
    );

  return (
    <div className={classes.toolbar}>
      <main className={classes.layout}>
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
          <Typography varient="h4" alignment="center"></Typography>
          <Stepper activeStep={activeStep} className={classes.stepper}>
            {steps.map((step) => (
              <Step key={step}>
                <StepLabel>{step}</StepLabel>
              </Step>
            ))}
          </Stepper>
          {activeStep === steps.length ? <Conformation /> : <Form />}
        </Paper>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Checkout;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why there are two calls for  ```fetchShippingCountries```  inside two ```useEffect```?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you might not be getting it is cause useEffect without any dependency runs only once , if you pass checkoutToken as a dependency then it will run every time checkoutToken props changes , the reason you are not able to access it first time is cause it may be undefined in first case

so replace useEffect like below

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if(checkoutToken && checkoutToken.id){
        fetchShippingCountries(checkoutToken);
    }
  }, [checkoutToken]);
```